# Is there a way to check data entry consistency in Google Forms this way?

Tags: google-forms

In the questionnaire I'm working with, there's a question like this:

- What was your facility's total revenue last year?

And a bunch of following questions asking about sources of that revenue, e.g.:

- Of which, how much came from sales?
- Of which, how much came from services?

etc.

Is there a way in Google Forms to ensure data entry consistency for questions like this? For example, at the end of entry of individual sources of revenue, if those sources don't add up to be equal to total revenue, there will be a pop-up message, e.g., "Data entry inconsistency. Please ensure that individual sources add up to be equal to the total revenue." The respondents can choose to "Return" to start again from the Total revenue field, or to "Proceed anyway", acknowledging that there's some issue with their data quality.

Comment: Frankly speaking, Google Forms are pretty primitive as far as surveys are concerned. I suggest investigating alternative platforms.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks. What may be an alternative you can suggest?

Comment: You can search for "online survey form comparison" and get articles like http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2014/11/10/best-online-survey-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Forms doesn't incluye a way  to validate consistency across several responses before submitting the form.